# What is boost's shared_ptr(shared_ptr<Y> const & r, T * p) used for?

Tags: c++, boost, shared-ptr, smart-pointers

`boost::shared_ptr` has an unusual constructor

```
template<class Y> shared_ptr(shared_ptr<Y> const & r, T * p);
```

and I am a little puzzled as to what this would be useful for. Basically it shares ownership with `r`, but `.get()` will return `p`. **not** `r.get()`!

This means you can do something like this:

```
int main() {
    boost::shared_ptr<int> x(new int);
    boost::shared_ptr<int> y(x, new int);

    std::cout << x.get() << std::endl;
    std::cout << y.get() << std::endl;

    std::cout << x.use_count() << std::endl;
    std::cout << y.use_count() << std::endl;
}
```

And you will get this:

```
0x8c66008
0x8c66030
2
2
```

Note that the pointers are separate, but they both claim to have a `use_count` of 2 (since they share ownership of the same object).

So, the `int` owned by `x` will exist as long as `x` **or** `y` is around. And if I understand the docs correct, the second `int` never gets destructed. I've confirmed this with the following test program:

```
struct T {
    T() { std::cout << "T()" << std::endl; }
    ~T() { std::cout << "~T()" << std::endl; }
};

int main() {
    boost::shared_ptr<T> x(new T);
    boost::shared_ptr<T> y(x, new T);

    std::cout << x.get() << std::endl;
    std::cout << y.get() << std::endl;

    std::cout << x.use_count() << std::endl;
    std::cout << y.use_count() << std::endl;
}
```

This outputs (as expected):

```
T()
T()
0x96c2008
0x96c2030
2
2
~T()
```

So... what is the usefulness of this unusual construct which shares ownership of one pointer, but **acts** like another pointer (which it does not own) when used.

Comment: TL;DR version: It creates a pointer to a sub-object of `r`.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

It is useful when you want to share a class member and an instance of the class is already a shared_ptr, like the following:

```
struct A
{
  int *B; // managed inside A
};

shared_ptr<A>   a( new A );
shared_ptr<int> b( a, a->B );
```

they share the use count and stuff. It is optimization for memory usage.

Comment: a good answer. clearly, in this example, we would want to keep `a`'s object around as long as `b` is around. I think we have a winner.

Comment: Not only an optimization for memory usage, but in the specific example, using a different approach would end up with a call to `delete( a->B )` that may be unexpected (consider `struct A { int b; }; shared_ptr<A> a(new A); shared_ptr<int> b( a, &a->b )`)

Comment: it is not only optimization for memory usage. It may have other uses;)
see my answer below..

Answer (score 8):

To expand on [leiz's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1403465/what-is-boosts-sharedptrsharedptry-const-r-t-p-used-for/1403512#1403512) and [piotr's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1403465/what-is-boosts-sharedptrsharedptry-const-r-t-p-used-for/1403521#1403521) answers, this description of `shared_ptr<>` 'aliasing' is from a WG21 paper, ["Improving `shared_ptr` for C++0x, Revision 2"](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2007/n2351.htm#aliasing):

> **III. Aliasing Support**
>
> Advanced users often require the
>   ability to create a `shared_ptr`
>   instance `p` that shares ownership with
>   another (master) `shared_ptr` `q` but
>   points to an object that is not a base
>   of `*q`. `*p` may be a member or an
>   element of `*q`, for example. This
>   section proposes an additional
>   constructor that can be used for this
>   purpose.
>
> An interesting side effect of this
>   increase of expressive power is that
>   now the `*_pointer_cast` functions can
>   be implemented in user code. The
>   `make_shared` factory function presented
>   later in this document can also be
>   implemented using only the public
>   interface of `shared_ptr` via the
>   aliasing constructor.
>
> **Impact:**
>
> This feature extends the interface of
>   `shared_ptr` in a backward-compatible
>   way that increases its expressive
>   power and is therefore strongly
>   recommended to be added to the C++0x
>   standard. It introduces no source- and
>   binary compatibility issues.
>
> **Proposed text:**
>
> Add to `shared_ptr`
>   [util.smartptr.shared] the following
>   constructor:
>
> > ```
> > template<class Y> shared_ptr( shared_ptr<Y> const & r, T * p );
> > ```
>
> Add the following to
>   [util.smartptr.shared.const]:
>
> > ```
> > template<class Y> shared_ptr( shared_ptr<Y> const & r, T * p );
> > ```
> >
> > *Effects:* Constructs a `shared_ptr` instance that stores `p` and *shares ownership with* `r`.
> >
> > *Postconditions:* `get() == p && use_count() == r.use_count()`.
> >
> > *Throws:* nothing.
> >
> > *[Note:* To avoid the possibility of a dangling pointer, the user 
> >     of this constructor must ensure that `p` remains valid at least 
> >     until the ownership group of `r` is destroyed. *--end note.]*
> >
> > *[Note:* This constructor allows creation of an *empty* `shared_ptr`
> >     instance with a non-NULL stored pointer. *--end note.]*

Answer (score 4):

You can also use this to keep dynamic casted pointers, i.e.:

```
class A {};
class B: public A {};

shared_ptr<A> a(new B);
shared_ptr<B> b(a, dynamic_cast<B*>(a.get()));
```

Comment: another interesting use that clearly falls into the category of "aliasing". Good point.

Answer (score 2):

You might have a pointer to some driver or a lower level api's data structure that may allocate additional data by its lower level api or other means. In this case it might be interesting to increase the use_count but return the additional data if the first pointer owns the other data pointers.

Answer (score 0):

For "`shared_ptr<B> b(a, dynamic_cast<B*>(a.get()));`"

I think it is not the recommended way using smart pointer.

The recommended way of doing this type conversion should be:

```
shared_ptr<B> b(a);
```

Since in Boost document it is mentioned that:

> `shared_ptr<T>` can be implicitly
>   converted to `shared_ptr<U>` whenever T*
>   can be implicitly converted to U*. In
>   particular, `shared_ptr<T>` is
>   implicitly convertible to `shared_ptr<T> const`, 
>   to `shared_ptr<U>` where U is an
>   accessible base of T, and to
>   `shared_ptr<void>`.

In addition to that, we also have **dynamic_pointer_cast**
which could directly do conversion on Smart Pointer object and both of these two methods would be much safer than the manually casting raw pointer way.

Answer (score 0):

I have put shared_ptr's aliasing constructor in use in my little library:

http://code.google.com/p/infectorpp/ (just my simple IoC container)

The point is that since I needed a shared_ptr of known type to be returned from a polymorphic class (that does not know the type). I was not able to implicitly  convert the shared_ptr to the type I needed.

In the file "[InfectorHelpers.hpp](http://code.google.com/p/infectorpp/source/browse/trunk/include/Infectorpp/InfectorHelpers.hpp)" (line 72-99) you can see that in action for the type IAnyShared.

Aliasing constructor creates shared_ptr that does not delete the pointers they are actually pointing to, but **they still increase the reference counter** to the original object and that can be tremendously usefull.

Basically you can create a pointer to anything using aliasing constructor and threat it as a reference counter.

```
//my class
std::shared_ptr<T> ist;
int a; //dummy variable. I need its adress

virtual std::shared_ptr<int> getReferenceCounter(){
    return std::shared_ptr<int>(ist,&a); //not intended for dereferencing
}

virtual void* getPtr(); //return raw pointer to T
```

now we have both "a reference counter" and a pointer to a istance of T, enough data to create something with the aliasing constructor

```
std::shared_ptr<T> aPtr( any->getReferenceCounter(), //share same ref counter 
               static_cast<T*>(any->getPtr()) ); //potentially unsafe cast!
```

I don't pretend to have invented this use for the aliasing constructor, but I never seen someone else doing the same. If you are guessing if that dirty code works the answer is yes.