# What type should I use for an index variable

Tags: c++, cuda

This is a best practices question.  I am making an array

```
type * x = malloc(size*sizeof(type));
```

AFAIK sizeof gives a return value of size_t.  Does that mean that I should use a size_t to declare, or pass around size?  Also when indexing the array should I also use a size_t for the index variable?  What is the best practice for these these?  This is not something that they taught in school, and now that I'm getting into serious c++ I want to know.

Also if anyone has references of where I can find best practices for this kind of stuff it would be helpful? Kind of an etiquette for programmers book.

EDIT:
The malloc should be cudaHostAlloc, or cudaMalloc, since I am developing a class that stores an array simultaneously on the device and host, and updates both at the same time.  So malloc here is just a place holder for what I'll actually be doing.

Comment: A good "best practice" is using `sizeof` with the variable in use: `type * x = (type*) malloc( size*sizeof *x );` That way if you later update the type in the left hand size you won't need to update the right hand side (`sizeof(type)`)

Comment: A good best practice for C++ is not to use `malloc()`.  Why are you using it?

Comment: I edited in the question that the malloc is simply a place holder to show that I am dynamically allocating memory.  I the final implementation I will be using the cuda interface to get at pinned memory ang gpu memory.  So no i will not be really using malloc, but what I will actually be doing is more complicated than the question requires.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In general, I use whatever minimizes the number of implicit or explicit casts and warning errors.  Generally there is a good reason why things are typed the way they are.  `size_t` is a good choice for array index, since it's `unsigned` and you don't generally want to access `myarray[-1]`, say.

btw since this is C++ you should get out of the habit of using `malloc` (`free`) which is part of CRT (C runtime library).  Use `new` (`delete`), preferably with [smart pointers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2454214/is-it-a-good-practice-to-always-use-smart-pointers) to minimize manual memory handling.

Once you have mastered the basics, a good practices reference (language-specific) is [Effective C++ by Scott Meyers](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0201924889).  The logical next step is [Effective STL](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0201749629).

Comment: One advantage with using int as an index is that you can iterate downwards and have a termination condition that checks if the index is >= 0.

Comment: True - or, you could use `array::rbegin()` and `array::rend()`

Comment: @steve - That is iff you've caught onto the best practice of using "smart" arrays rather than the raw types.

Comment: @Noah - even without that, it's possible (and faster) to use pointer arithmetic not indices. Many STL algorithms work with pointer ranges too.

Comment: I'd agree with that.  Unfortunately I don't believe there's a pointer->iterator wrapper that would be necessary for a reverse iterator.  I'm also not 100% sure iterating to one less than the start of an array is OK from the standard's POV.  I seem to recall a big discussion somewhere at one point that resulted in the fact that some architectures can actually have problems with first-1 and last+2.  For most purposes I doubt that matters though.

Comment: @Inverse - yes but the point is to express intended semantics of the index variable, not *per se* to prevent bad code from being written.

Comment: In most cases it is better to use std::vector than new/delete

Comment: @Ben, agreed, but in context (OP is new to C++) new/delete is a good first step vs `malloc/free`. Since I see this is CUDA, I doubt `vector` is available.

Comment: @Steve: In most cases it is better to use std::vector than new/delete, *especially* when you're new to C++.

Answer (score 4):

In reference to your follow-on question:

The best reference I have used for general high-level programming "current good practices" sort of thing is:

[Code Complete by Steve McConnell (ISBN 0-7356-1967-0)](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0735619670)

I reference it all the time.  When my company formalized its coding standards, I wrote them based off of it.  It doesn't go into design or architecture as much, but for actually banging out code, the book is appropriately named.

Comment: The end of the question says: "Also if anyone has references of where I can find best practices for this kind of stuff it would be helpful? Kind of an etiquette for programmers book."  This is what I provided.  I didn't realize that we were supposed to stick to the title of the question, and not stray to answering follow-on questions.

Answer (score 2):

`cudaMalloc` takes a size of type `size_t`, so for consistency, that's what you should use for indices.

Answer (score -1):

Well, since you've already abandoned best practice, even GOOD practice, by using malloc...why does it really matter?

That said, I generally use size_t unless I need a type that can go negative for various semi-rare conditions.

Answer (score -1):

I would prefer `int` over `size_t` for a couple reasons:

1. primitive types should be preferred unless the typedef provides something fundamentally new, `size_t` here doesn't
2. the `size_t` is defined differently on different systems, possibly creating surprises for some developers
3. signed `int` avoids `for (size_t i=9; i>=0; --i)` bugs, as well as other bugs in conditionals, e.g. `if (result < 1)` or `if ((i-2)/2 < 1)`

`size_t` is a useless abstraction that masks undesired behavior by silencing underflows

Comment: 1.  `size_t` is a standardized typedef for a primitive type.  2. `int` also varies from system to system.  3. A good compiler will warn you when you say `i >= 0` for an unsigned type.  `int` masks undesired behavior by silencing overflows.

Comment: I've arrived here to argue 12 years later!
I agree very much with point 3 here ^. How do you iterate backwards with size_t ?
If the index is size_t, and its 0, 0--, becomes LONG_MAX.