# What is the best type to use for an index variable in a for loop in C++?

Tags: c++, for-loop, types

There have already been some questions on this topic ([1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3174850/what-is-the-correct-type-for-array-indexes-in-c), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4035112/what-type-should-i-use-for-an-index-variable), [3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26135284/for-loop-index-type-deduction-best-practice)). The thing is that there doesn't seem to be a clear-cut answer. Some answers suggest `size_t` ([1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3198276/12501684), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31090426/12501684)), some suggest `ptrdiff_t` ([1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31090426/12501684), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28977333/12501684)). Other options include `int`, `uint32_t`, `auto` or using `decltype` on `.size()` of a container or the member type `size_type`.

This question may seem unsuitable as being opinion-based, but I don't think that's the case. Just because there isn't already a consensus on which type to use, doesn't mean that there cannot exist an objective answer. This is due to the fact that the different choices aren't only aesthetical, but can actually influence the behavior of the code.

For example, using an index variable type with mismatched signedness in the loop condition will cause compiler warnings, [like this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7443222/how-do-i-deal-with-signed-unsigned-mismatch-warnings-c4018). Also, using a type that has a range that is too small can cause an overflow, which in the case of signed types is UB. At the same time, in some cases changing the loop counter type can cause "[crazy performance deviations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25078285/replacing-a-32-bit-loop-counter-with-64-bit-introduces-crazy-performance-deviati)".

I also wanted to find out what is the most popular, though not necessarily the best, way to create for loop, so I used GitHub<sup>*</sup> search to find out. Here are the results:

| Loop type | Code result count on GitHub (averaged; "manual" loop + range-based) |
| --- | --- |
| [`for (int`](https://github.com/search?q=%22for%20int%22%20language%3Ac%2B%2B&type=code) | 15.8m |
| [`for (size_t`](https://github.com/search?q=%22for%20size_t%22%20language%3Ac%2B%2B&type=code) | 11.6m |
| [`for (auto`](https://github.com/search?q=%22for%20auto%20%3B%22%20language%3Ac%2B%2B&type=code) | 7.5m |
| [`for (uint32_t`](https://github.com/search?q=%22for%20uint32_t%22%20language%3Ac%2B%2B&type=code) | 2.3m |
| [`std::for_each`](https://github.com/search?q=%22std%3A%3Afor_each%22%20language%3Ac%2B%2B&type=code) | 501k |
| [`for (ptrdiff_t`](https://github.com/search?q=%22for%20ptrdiff_t%22%20language%3Ac%2B%2B&type=code) | 98.7k |
| [`for (decltype`](https://github.com/search?q=%22for%20decltype%22%20language%3Ac%2B%2B&type=code) | 77.5k |

There are certainly large differences in occurrence count between the different loop types, however, there doesn't seem to be a clear outstanding leader.

As such I post this question asking, what is the best type to use for the index variable in a for loop in C++ or what are the rules or conditions based on which this type should be chosen?

<sub>*: The GitHub search tool produces varying results for "code results" (count) each time, so I averaged 26 values. As the search is text-based it includes both results of the form `for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i)` and `for (int i : vec)`.</sub>

Comment: This is like asking "what is the best car to drive". Can you try answering this question, yourself? Do you think you can give a meaningful answer? In order to pick the right type for ***any*** variable in C++ you need to fully understand ***how*** that variable is used, and whether one particular type will work better than all the rest, so it all depends on each individual piece of code where the loop appears. And in some cases it won't make any difference, whatsoever, since the compiler will optimize away any differences.

Comment: Well, this ***is*** opinion-based. Also, the answer will be *very* dependent on what the nature of the `for` loop is: what are you comparing the index with? If the comparison is with an STL `.size()` result, then `size_t` would seem best; if it is with a `.distance()` result, then `ptrdiff_t` would seem more appropriate. And so on, and so forth ...

Comment: define "best", fastest? least memory? least chance of causing a bug? usable in the most places? most readable?

Comment: 1. Avoid using loops explicitly; use the C++ standard library algorithms whenever possible. 2. The type of the index is normally a function of the stopping conditional. 3. Using `auto` is pernicious.

Comment: What loop type to use depends on what the loop variable is used for.  If it is used for indexing, it probably should be `std::size_t`.  If it is used for some integer math, it should probably be `int`.  If it is used for some `double` floating point increment, it should probably be `int` and then calculate the current `double` from the loop variable.

Comment: Huh. If this is considered opinion based it would be better to close the rest to avoid setting bad examples